# Having trouble with SkipException, testNG, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to selenium UI automation and I am trying my hands on with a simple application. I am using java with testNG. I need to integrate this test with CI and the test environment url will be different with every deployment. I am passing this as a parameter, difference between test and prod environment is that in the test, there won't be any login screen hence there is no need for authentication but my test verifies login and a login method. I need to be able to skip this test based on the URL supplied. Here is my code and the problem is testNG always suggests that the test was skipped but I can see it executing the login method. Please help me correct or understand what mistake I am committing.

```
public class Login {

  WebDriver driver;

  //Parameter - test environment URL
  String url = System.getProperty("environment");


  @Test (priority = 1)
  public void verifyLogin() {

    //Skip verifyLogin test in non prod environments
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(url);

    if (url=="www.google.com")
    //If url matches production url then execute the test, if url doesn't match production URL then skip login test as there won't be any authentication/login in non prod
    {

        LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);
        login.signIn();
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Application Name", "Login failed,");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Page title is " + title);
        driver.close();
    }

    else if (url!="www.google.com"){

      throw new SkipException("Skipping this test");

    }

  }
  @Test(priority = 2)
  public void userKey() {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get(url);

      //If URL equals prod then call the login method to be able to login to the app else just execute the userKey method without having the need to login

      if (url=="www.google.com");
      {
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);
        login.signIn();
      }

      AccountManagementPage userKey = new AccountManagementPage(driver);
      userKey.key();
      driver.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very exact use case is well explained [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-skip-tests-based-on-test-environment/) without throwing SkipException.

The idea is to create a custom annotation for the methods to be skipped & read the methods using `IMethodInterceptor` - decide to execute or not behind the scenes.

---

Updated for the question in the comment section:

You do not have to worry about 'TestEnvironment' or 'TestParameters' class.Just directly use the production check logic here.

```
Predicate<IMethodInstance> isTestExecutingOnProduction = (tip) -> {
    return system.getProperty("env").
                              .equals("<production check here>");
};
```

Comment: Hey vins, thanks for your comment, unfortunately I don't think I understand well due to my limitation, do you have a sample project with this implementation somewhere that will help me understand? any help much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: @mathur , check this site - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-skip-tests-based-on-test-environment/

Comment: Thanks Vins, I have a few basic questions, I am using a variable to pass url from maven like this "String url = System.getProperty("env");" and its in the base class. What I am not clear is how do I incorporate the "TestEnvironment" enum and the "TestParameter" class. IS "NotOnProduction.class" the retention annotation?

Comment: @mathur, unable to answer in the comment section. check the updated answer